# What's the better practice for temporary device pointers in cuda, reuse a fixed device pointer or create and free device pointers?

Tags: cuda

In cuda kernel functions there's no automatic garbage collection. What's the better practice for temporary device pointers in Cuda? Reuse a fixed device pointer, or create and free device pointers?

For example, to write a Cuda kernel function for sum of squared errors between two vectors, it's more convenient to have a temporary device pointer for storing the difference of the two vectors and then sum the squares of elements of this temporary device pointer. An option is to allocate a temporary device pointer and then free it for every function call, and an another option is to have a constantly reused temporary device pointer.

What's the better practice between these two options?

Comment: This could be primarily opinion-based, but I posted an answer based from a performance & buffer size point of view.

Comment: For your particular example use-case, you don't want to store any intermediate result as your problem is memory bound already. What you want is to calculate de square difference in registers and use shuffle,  atomics and or shared memory for reduction depending on your architecture. Besides this comment, runtime allocation is very rarely the preferred option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use cudaMalloc and cudaFree and avoid multiple allocations, you should avoid using dynamic memory allocation within the kernel, as it has an additional cost on performance and is limited in size depending on the launch configuration :

> The following API functions get and set the heap size:
>
> ```
> cudaDeviceGetLimit(size_t* size, cudaLimitMallocHeapSize)
> cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, size_t size)
> ```
>
> The heap size granted will be at least size bytes. cuCtxGetLimit()and
>   cudaDeviceGetLimit() return the currently requested heap size.
>
> The actual memory allocation for the heap occurs when a module is
>   loaded into the context, either explicitly via the CUDA driver API
>   (see Module), or implicitly via the CUDA runtime API (see CUDA C
>   Runtime).

See [Dynamic global memory allocation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations) in CUDA Documentation.